# Automated call to class static functions C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, static-methods

I'm working on a project executed on an ESP32 micro controller (c++11) and I would like to implement a class method that could take Class References (not instances of those classes) as arguments in order to execute static methods of those classes.

I manage to implement the following working solution :

```
#include <iostream>

    class Model
{
public:
    static void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "Model.foo invoked" << std::endl;
    };
};

class ModelA: public Model
{
public:
    static void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "ModelA.foo invoked" << std::endl;
    };
};

class ModelB: public Model
{
public:
    static void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "ModelB.foo invoked" << std::endl;
    };
};


class Manager
{
public:

    template <class T = Model>
    void callFoo()
    {
        T::foo();
    }

    template<class T = Model, class ... args>
    void setup()
    {
       callFoo<T>();
       callFoo<args...>();
    }

};


int main()
{

    Manager manager;
    manager.setup<ModelA, ModelB>();

    return 0;
}
```

The output meets the expected result :

> ModelA.foo invoked
>
> ModelB.foo invoked

But I have the feeling that this approach is at best a poor hack...

Does someone has a better way to implement this (ideally without using a template) ?

Thank you in advance.

Vincent.

Comment: This design looks questionable to me. You're doing name hiding with your `Model` derivatives and the whole type hierarchy doesn't make much sense in the example. What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Hi Timo, Thank you for your answer. You are right, this design is nothing less that questionnable ;-) It's not explicit in my example but all Model classes that inherit from the Model class are singletons. I would like to implement a setup method on a Manager class that can take any number of Model subclass "class references" (not instances) and call a static method of Model for each of those references.

Comment: I think what you have is the best you can do within C++11. With C++17, this works:
`template<typename... Models>
    void setup()
    {
        (Models::foo(), ...);
    }`

Comment: It's unclear what the role of class `Model` is in all this. The code would work just as well when `ModelA` and `ModelB` do not derive from `Model`, and when `Model` doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Hi Igor, thank you for taking the time to answer. I'm stuck here with c++11 (micro controller environment). Model class in the real project is a template singleton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to dispatch static member functions of any type based on references of that type, you can easily do this by (slightly) abusing function template parameter inference:

```
template <typename T>
void call(T const& = *static_cast<T const*>(nullptr)) {
  T::foo();
}

struct Magic {
  static void foo() {}
};
struct MoreMagic {
  static void foo() {}
};

int main() {
  call<Magic>();
  call(MoreMagic());
  MoreMagic m;
  call(m);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer bitmask. May be I missed something but this solution, even if the template method is much more versatile is a bit similar to the one I post originally no ?

Comment: Yes it is with the distinction that you can dispatch based on a reference to the full type and I threw out the unnecessary polymorphy. According to your question you wanted to call a static function depending on the type of a reference, which is exactly what this does. Perhaps I misunderstood what you were trying to accomplish? Do you want to dispatch based on the runtime-type of a polymorphic object?

Comment: ... however, if you are on a micro controller you might want to go easy on polymorphy ...

Comment: Hello bitmask. Understood, you are right polymorphism is not necessary here. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use typeclasses as parameters. Not currently available in "C++".

Yet, for your specific case, since all static methods have the same function prototype, or function signature, you could do some workarounds.

First, change each static method into a virtual method:

```
#include <iostream>

class Model
{
  public:
    virtual Foo(void* Args)
    {
      str::cout << "method Model.DoFoo( ) invoked. << std::endln;
    } // DoFoo

}; // class Model

class ModelA: Model
{
  public:
    virtual Foo(void* Args)
    {
      str::cout << "method ModelA.DoFoo( ) invoked. << std::endln;
    } // DoFoo

}; // class ModelA

class ModelB: Model
{
  public:
    virtual Foo(void* Args) override
    {
      str::cout << "method ModelB.DoFoo( ) invoked << std::endln;
  } // DoFoo

}; // class ModelB
```

Second, add a local function, not a method, to generate an instance of each class as a result:

```
 Model* ModelFactory( )
 {
   Model* M = new Model ( );
   return M;
 } // ModelFactory

 Model* ModelAFactory( )
 {
   Model* M = new ModelA( );
   return M;
 } // ModelFactory

 Model* ModelBFactory( )
 {
   Model* M = new ModelB ( );
   return M;
 } // ModelFactory
```

Three, your `Manager` class, instead of "variadic" or "..." parameters, you will add a vector as a single parameter, to store references to those factory functions.

And a parameter to store that vector.

```
#include <vector>

typedef
   Model* (*Factory) (void* Args);

class Manager
{
  public:
     std::vector<Factory>* Factories;

    void setup(std::vector<Factory>* AFactories)
    {
      this.Factories = AFactories;
    } // setup

} ; // class Manager
```

Note that the factories work as typeclasses parameters.

Four, a method to the `Manager` class to retrieve each factory from the vector, execute it, generate an instance, call the replacement virtual method, and later, dispose the instance.

```
class Manager
{
  public:
     std::vector<Factory>* Factories;

    void setup(std::vector<Factory>* AFactories)
    {
      this.Factories = AFactories;
    } // setup

    void run(void* Args)
    {
      for (Factory EachFactory : this.Factories)
      {
         Model* M = EachFactory( );
           M->Foo(Args);
         delete M;
      } // for
    } // void

} ; // class Manager
```

Five, build the example:

```
int main( )
{
  Manager* M = new Manager( );

  // prepare compiletime list of classes
  std::vector<Factory>* Factories =
    new std::vector<Factory>*(2);

  Factories->insert(&ModelAFactory);
  Factories->insert(&ModelBFactory);

  // assign list to Manager
  M->setup(Factories);

  // execute each class method
  // with same parameters
  M->run( nullptr );

  // drop list
  delete Factories ( );

  delete M;
} // main
```

Your `Model` class and subclasses may have other operations, not related at all, and still do not conflict, with the `static` methods replaced by `virtual` methods.

Note, that newer versions of C++ standard can do something similar to this with concepts, and variadic arguments' templates.

Comment: Thank you umlcat. I think I understand your solution but I should have mentioned on my post that Model is a singleton template class of a small "MVC framework" for an ESP32 micro controller. The goal was that the traditional "getInstance" method of each Model Singleton was called at startup before it was explicitly called in the the user code. Thank you for your time.